Accessing network share results in "The network path was not found"
Attempting to access a share on Windows Server 2019 results in:
net use z: "\\servername\sharename"

System error 53 has occurred. The network path was not found.

The error also occurs when using File Explorer using the UNC path, the fully qualified name, and IP address.
However, mklink works:
mklink /D "C:\NetworkShares\RemoteCDrive"
I'm testing on as administrator on a domain controller.
Is there a policy that blocks this type of mount?

I've found that it doesn't work without the double backslash before servername net use z: \\servername\sharename. I don't think spaces are allowed in the share name, so quotes aren't required.

There needs to be at least some symptom elaboration. Such as access by FQDN and IP address.

After much research I found that the problem lies in the order of the network provider.
I also found a post about this that explains the solution.
file-explorer-windows-cant-find-servershare-check-spelling-try!
In my case it was that between the network providers there were  spaces "RDPNP, LanmanWorkstation, WebClient"
I removed them and after this I could access my SMB shares.
I hope this helps someone because this error was really difficult to solve.
